# Creating named relations in Rails 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to learn Rails and I'm struggling to understand how self relations are declared using the ActiveRecord component.

If I have something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :comments
end
```

Being the related comments the comment's replies and the comment's parent, how am I supposed to access them if they have the same name? I can't just do `comment.comments`, they would need to have different names.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the [self-joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) docs, but it'd be `belongs_to :comment`, not comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, `belongs_to` is a singular association, so it would be:

```
belongs_to :comment
```

... and you would have no name conflict.

But for cases where you do have conflicts, you can always rename relations, for example:

```
has_many :comments
has_many :recent_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :limit => 10, :order => 'id DESC'
```

See more examples of options for associations [in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use singular for `belongs_to` associations:

```
    belongs_to :comment
```

It looks like you are trying to create a tree-like structure of `Comment`s. You might want to take a look at gems like [paginary](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).

Answer (score 0):

The first symbol passed to the has_many method is the name you want to specify. Rails uses the Convention over configuration principle, so it takes the related class' name from it to, but you can specify it like this:

```
has_many :rel, :class_name => "Class"
```